# Vertically Aligining an Image

Tags: html, css

I have a document structure in which an unordered list contains divs with images in them. The divs all have a set height of 150px, but some of the images happen to be smaller than that. Is there a way in CSS to vertically position the images within the div itself.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/xQ7pJ/

My HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            <img src=""/>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Flagged as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

```
<img src="" style="vertical-align:middle;"/>
```

The vertical align property can also be set to "Text-top"

More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to apply the image as a background image on the `div` itself and set the background position to 50% + no-repeat.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div style="background: url(http://bestvaluesupply.devsiteonline.com/ProdImages/SEY%2098-50-1.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sbeliv01/xQ7pJ/2/

Although in this case, if the image is larger than the 150px container then it will be cut off at those constraints.

Other than that method, if you don't need to worry about IE7 or less and you're only planning to display that single image within the `div`, then you can set the `div` to `display: table-cell` and then set the `vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;`.

`ul li div { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; }`

http://jsfiddle.net/sbeliv01/xQ7pJ/3/